# issue with PDO execute in PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Hey guys I have this code:

```
$tdata = "INSERT INTO insuranceverificationdisclaimer (InsCoName, PhoneNumber, Policy, InsuredName, MailingAdrs, EffDate, ExpDate, Email1, YrVehicle , Make, Model, VIN, TraineeUserName, EmpName, EmpCoName, AgencyNumber, SignDate, AgentName, AgentPhone, AgentEmail , Combinedlimit, bodyinjur ,bodyinjureachacc , propertydmg ) VALUES (':insur',':phone',':policy' ,':insurname',':mailingad',':effdate',':expdate',':email',':yr',':make',':model',':vin',':user',':empname',':empcomp',':agnum',':signdate',':agname',':agphone',':agemail',':csl',':body',':acc',':prop')";
$tinsertdata = $DBH->prepare($tdata);
$tinsertdata->execute(array(':insur' => $compname, ':phone' => $phone , ':policy' => $policynum, ':insurname' => $nameofPolicyholder, ':mailingad' => $newMailingAdrs, ':effdate' => $Policyeffdate, ':expdate' => $Policyexpdate, ':email' => $newEmployeeEmail, ':yr' => $YearOfVehicle, ':make' => $MakeOfVehicle, ':model' => $ModelOfVehicle, ':vin' => $Vehicleid, ':user' => $username, ':empname' => $EmployeeName, ':empcomp' => $EmployeeCompanyName, ':agnum' => $Agencynum, ':signdate' => $TodaysDate, ':agname' => $agentname, ':agphone' => $agentphone, ':agemail' => $agentemail, ':csl' => $singlelimit, ':body' => $bodyinjur, ':acc' => $eachacc, ':prop' => $propertydmg ));
```

But once I hit the execute it will not go forth.  The funny thing is this came up out of no where based on if you enter a value into a text field called combined limits which is the Combinedlimits on the database insert. It just blanks the page out and it fails on the execute.  I don't see anything wrong so I don't know why it is doing this.  I checked to see if the field in the database is like the others and it is so I don't get it.

Combinedlimit is a `int(100)` with a default of `'0'` if nothing is entered.  Not if you don't enter anything into that field on the form it works correctly.

here is the input box code for the combinedlimit:

```
<span class="limitsection">Combined Single Limit for bodily 
injury and property damage liability: </span>
<div class="InputInner"> <input type="text" 
name="singlelimit" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"  
class="combinedinput" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['singlelimit']; ?>">
</div><!----- END    .InputInner ---------->
```

the keypress just only allows the user to enter numbers.

If you can help I would appreciate :)

EDIT:

I just recieved this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: ':csl' for column 'Combinedlimit' at row 1' in E:\web\pcgprote\PCG\insert.php:545 Stack trace: #0 E:\web\pcgprote\PCG\insert.php(545): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in E:\web\pcgprote\PCG\insert.php on line 545

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No I tried turning on error messaging but nothing.

Comment: I hate SQL Server.  Just to ask, are you using the mssql driver or sqlsrv native driver?

Comment: MySQL.....I don't get it because in the database the combinedlimits is an int(100) and the value being entered in the form is a number?

Comment: Ack, just realized SQLSTATE isn't a sql server error.  but for the record, i still hate sql server.  sorry for the mixup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to quote the placeholders inside the prepared statement (i.e. not `':insur'`, but simply `:insur`). PDO handles quoting the values.

Comment: You get the point brotha thank you so much!  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

After too much trouble with PDO bindings I found this solution:

[PDO identify missing bound variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357786/pdo-identify-missing-bound-variables/14359121#14359121)