# How to check named placeholders==execute array keys?ok:throw exception

Tags: php, exception, pdo, error-handling

Is there a standard way by which we can match named parameters with array keys and if not found then throw an exception.

Say for example in below code prepare says that there is field1 but the execute array has no such key:

```
try{
    $statement = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tablename SET field = :field WHERE field2 = :field1");
    $statement->execute(array(
                    ':field' => $value,
                    ':field2'=>$value2
                    ));                 
    }
    catch(PDOException $pdo_error){
                echo "Error msg..";
            }
```

Comment: If you've enabled `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`, the `catch` block should execute.

Comment: You should get the exception shown in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357786/pdo-identify-missing-bound-variables

Comment: You need to display the error message from `$pdo_error` instead of just echoing your own error string.

Comment: the solution in link posted by you is user defined..i had gone through that prior to posting this question..isn't there some inbuilt/standard feature/ way..what to display is secondary..first the program execution should reach the `catch` block

Comment: I wasn't pointing you to a solution, just the question. It shows that PDO automatically raises an exception when there are missing placeholders.

Comment: also to add, if i deliberately put some error in the prepare query then the exception is caught..

Comment: There are hundreds of questions here where they report getting that error message because they had a mismatchin between their placeholders and bound variables.

Comment: sir, to my little knowledge, in such questions the exception was raised due to having mismatch in number of bound variables to the number of tokens but not due to mismatch in names..

Comment: It's only a mismatch in number if you use unnamed placeholders with `?`. If you use named placeholders, you get the same exception, but it actually means some are missing. Look at the query in the question I linked to.

Comment: Do you get the exception if you leave `:field2` out of the execute array?

Comment: leaving `:field2` gives `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number` and typing error in `prepare` now gives `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`. The problem was this line in catch block - `echo "Failed to execute query:\n" . $statement . "\nWith Error:\n" . $pdo_error->getMessage();` removing `$statement` works fine..Thanks..

Comment: The BIG LESSON - Never turn off error reporting on development system.